# How do we add dataframes with same id?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm a beginner in data science learning. Gone through the pandas topic and I found a task here, which I'm unable to understand what is wrong. Let me explain the problem.

I have three data frames:

```
gold = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'France', 'Russia'],
                         'Medals': [15, 13, 9]}
                    )
silver = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'Germany', 'Russia'],
                        'Medals': [29, 20, 16]}
                    )
bronze = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['France', 'USA', 'UK'],
                        'Medals': [40, 28, 27]}
                    )
```

Here, I need to add to all the medals into one column, country in another. When I added it was showing NAN. So, I filled the NAN with zero values, still I'm unable to get deserved output.

Code:

```
    gold.set_index('Country', inplace = True)
    silver.set_index('Country',inplace = True)
    bronze.set_index('Country', inplace = True)
    Total = silver.add(gold,fill_value = 0)
    Total = bronze.add(silver,fill_value = 0)
    Total = gold + silver + bronze
    print(Total)
```

Actual Output:

```
                Medals
    Country        
     France      NaN
     Germany     NaN
     Russia      NaN
     UK          NaN
     USA        72.0
```

Expected:

```
               Medals
     Country        
     USA        72.0
     France     53.0
     UK         27.0
     Russia     25.0
     Germany    20.0
```

Let me know what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `concat` with `groupby` `sum`

```
pd.concat([gold,silver,bronze]).groupby('Country').sum()
Out[1306]: 
         Medals
Country        
France       53
Germany      20
Russia       25
UK           27
USA          72
```

Fixing your code

```
silver.add(gold,fill_value = 0).add(bronze,fill_value=0)
```

if we expect floating point:

```
pd.concat([gold,silver,bronze]).groupby('Country').sum().astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# For a video solution of the code, copy-paste the following link on your browser:
# https://youtu.be/p0cnApQDotA

import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

# Defining the three dataframes indicating the gold, silver, and bronze medal counts
# of different countries
gold = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'France', 'Russia'],
                         'Medals': [15, 13, 9]}
                    )
silver = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'Germany', 'Russia'],
                        'Medals': [29, 20, 16]}
                    )
bronze = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['France', 'USA', 'UK'],
                        'Medals': [40, 28, 27]}
                    )

# Set the index of the dataframes to 'Country' so that you can get the countrywise
# medal count
gold.set_index('Country', inplace = True)
silver.set_index('Country', inplace = True) 
bronze.set_index('Country', inplace = True) 

# Add the three dataframes and set the fill_value argument to zero to avoid getting
# NaN values
total = gold.add(silver, fill_value = 0).add(bronze, fill_value = 0)

# Sort the resultant dataframe in a descending order
total = total.sort_values(by = 'Medals', ascending = False)

# Print the sorted dataframe
print(total)
```